# React Native: Uncaught (in promise) Error: DeltaPatcher should receive a base Bundle when being initialized

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have lately come across this error message in the http://localhost:8081/debugger-ui/ that says:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: DeltaPatcher should receive a base Bundle when being initialized
    at DeltaPatcher.applyDelta 
    at deltaUrlToBlobUrl
    at async getBlobUrl 
    at async WebSocket.ws.onmessage 
applyDelta  
deltaUrlToBlobUrl       
async function (async)      
ws.onmessage
```

This error occurs when I attempt to open my React Native application from the simulator and although the `index.ios.js` files build successfully, the application stays stuck on the splashscreen with the above error.

I do not know what it is referring to or where to begin to debug this or what package this `DeltaPatcher` is coming from.

As far as what I was doing prior to getting this error, this is what I was doing:

- Package fix for react-native tab view
- Had to remove npm-shrinkwrap.json to run npm install
- had to uninstall and reinstall react-native-splash-screen to get past
  build failure with xcode
- Had to create new auth.token in Sentry with project:write permissions
  to get past 403 error
- Manually completely remove Instabug from project
- Fix for Spinkit and `alerts.filter` errors

  After this the application was working correctly, but then I had to
  resolve the following errors in Xcode.
- Removed every reference to `8CBD27422B744FC9C0407AA3` related to
  `PhaseScriptExecution` error
- Refactored configuration to previous version to eliminate
  AppReactNativeCrashed bug
- modified Podfile configuration to reflect AppCenter upgrade
- removing instabug reference and spinkit references

Then I recalled that I had installed Metro version 29 in an attempt to resolve another issue. So I completely removed Metro as a package but that has not resolved it.

The script I am running is `react-native run-ios` and this is my `package.json` file:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "nps",
    "test": "nps setup && nps test",
    "build": "nps build",
    "prepare": "nps patcher",
    "setup": "nps setup && nps appcenter",
    "react-devtools": "react-devtools"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "appcenter": "2.0.0",
    "appcenter-analytics": "2.0.0",
    "appcenter-crashes": "2.0.0",
    "axios": "0.16.2",
    "date-fns": "^1.29.0",
    "lodash": "4.17.4",
    "moment": "2.20.1",
    "payment": "2.3.0",
    "prop-types": "15.6.0",
    "react": "16.8.3",
    "react-native": "0.59.9",
    "react-native-autoheight-webview": "0.6.1",
    "react-native-calendar-events": "1.6.1",
    "react-native-device-info": "0.21.5",
    "react-native-exception-handler": "2.8.9",
    "react-native-image-progress": "1.0.1",
    "react-native-immediate-phone-call": "1.0.0",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "0.4.4",
    "react-native-keyboard-manager": "4.0.13-12",
    "react-native-material-buttons": "0.5.0",
    "react-native-material-dropdown": "0.5.2",
    "react-native-material-tabs": "3.5.0",
    "react-native-material-textfield": "0.10.0",
    "react-native-onesignal": "3.0.7",
    "react-native-popup-menu": "0.8.3",
    "react-native-sentry": "0.32.0",
    "react-native-size-matters": "0.1.0",
    "react-native-splash-screen": "3.0.6",
    "react-native-svg": "6.3.1",
    "react-native-swipe-view": "https://github.com/jjd314/react-native-swipe-view",
    "react-native-tab-view": "1.3.2",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "6.1.0",
    "react-native-xcode-packager": "0.1.0",
    "react-navigation": "1.5.11",
    "react-redux": "5.0.6",
    "reactotron-react-native": "3.5.0",
    "reactotron-redux": "3.1.0",
    "recompose": "0.26.0",
    "redux": "4.0.1",
    "redux-thunk": "2.2.0",
    "replace-in-file": "3.1.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.4.5",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining": "7.2.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "7.4.5",
    "async": "2.6.0",
    "babel-cli": "6.24.1",
    "babel-eslint": "8.0.2",
    "babel-jest": "23.0.0",
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "3.0.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "1.4.0",
    "babel-preset-flow": "6.23.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "6.24.1",
    "babel-watch": "2.0.6",
    "chalk": "1.1.3",
    "detox": "8.2.3",
    "eslint": "4.12.0",
    "eslint-import-resolver-babel-module": "4.0.0-beta.3",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "2.3.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "7.5.1",
    "flow-bin": "0.46.0",
    "fs-extra": "5.0.0",
    "jest": "23.0.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.54.1",
    "nps": "5.7.1",
    "nps-utils": "^1.5.0",
    "patch-package": "5.1.1",
    "postinstall-prepare": "1.0.1",
    "prettier": "1.8.2",
    "prettier-eslint": "8.2.2",
    "react-devtools": "3.6.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.2.0",
    "redux-mock-store": "1.3.0",
    "yargs": "8.0.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native",
    "setupTestFrameworkScriptFile": "./jest-setup.js",
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "/node_modules/(?!parse)/"
    ],
    "unmockedModulePathPatterns": [
      "react",
      "react-navigation",
      "axios",
      "redux",
      "redux-thunk",
      "lodash",
      "date-fns"
    ],
    "verbose": true
  },
  "detox": {
    "configurations": {
      "ios.sim.debug": {
        "binaryPath": "ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/NFIBEngage.app",
        "build": "xcodebuild -workspace ios/NFIBEngage.xcworkspace -configuration Debug -scheme NFIBEngage -sdk iphonesimulator -derivedDataPath ios/build",
        "type": "ios.simulator",
        "name": "iPhone 6"
      }
    },
    "test-runner": "jest"
  }
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/24434#issuecomment-495565849

Comment: @MedetTleukabiluly, yes I took a look at that. I Googled Fu the heck out of this error before I posted it here.

Comment: What if you just turn off debugger-ui, or reinstall plugin

Comment: @MedetTleukabiluly, it seems like the error is related to metro. I did not originally have a Metro package on this application, so I removed it, but that has not fixed it yet. I will try to remove node modules and reinstall everything without metro.

Comment: I was able to fix my problem, the real log that helped me was in metro log, it was related to firebase

Comment: @simo, in my case I am not using firebase. At this point my app just crashes with the following errors: `Unhandled JS Exception: Cannot create styled-component for component: [object Object]` and `AppRegistry is not a callable module`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay so after I removed Metro version 29, I just kept running these commands repeatedly:

`rm -rf node_modules && npm install && npm run setup && react-native run-ios`

and now it boots past the splash screen with yet another, but more familiar error.

Comment: can you please share run script? can you share your package.json file?

Comment: @simo, thanks for taking an interest. I have included the info you asked for. I am currently getting an app that just continues to crash, by crash meaning it opens the splash screen and just stays there. I am at my wits end here with what could be wrong except that its a package somewhere not working with version 0.59.9 of RN, but their documentation has not been forthcoming as far as what packages work with this version. And thats just on the `ios` side, on the `android` side, I get this error: `Task 'installDebug' not found in project ':app'. Some candidates are: 'installDevDebug'`

Comment: @simo, so what I posted in the comments above, is happening regardless of the fact that now my project is successfully creating a `main.jsbundle` file which it was not before, because I changed `index.ios.js` to `index.js`

Comment: Thanks @Daniel, I hope your issue will be fixed

Comment: @simo, thank you, I am open to suggestions or if you can share this post with anyone who may have an idea.